# Postgresql replace numbers after specific letter

Tags: regex, postgresql

I have text strings like the following:

```
g06, f03, k090
```

And I would like to remove all zeros that immediately follow a letter. So the output would be:

```
g6, f3, k90
```

I can do something like:

```
select regexp_replace('k090','0','')
```

But this will replace all 0’s and not just the one immediately following a letter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```sql
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE('g06, f03, k090', '([[:alpha:]])0+', '\1', 'g')
```

Here,

- `([[:alpha:]])` - captures a single letter into Group 1
- `0+` - matches one or more zeros.

The replacement pattern is `\1`, a replacement backreference to Group 1 value (so it is not removed).

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/j4QMPG/1) ([DB fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=bbe069584e7b728c35083b753e81f296)).

Comment: Thanks so much, this is exactly what I’m looking for!